# Наилучшая реализация APN (Apple push Notification)

Tags: c#, java, objective-c, ios

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, наилучшую реализацию APN сервиса на C# и на JAVA. Хотелось бы узнать, на что ставки сделать лучше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [APNS-Sharp](https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp) для C#.

Есть ещё [Moon-APNS](https://github.com/arashnorouzi/Moon-APNS) тоже для C#, но проект менее живой.

Для Java есть: [JavaPNS 2.2](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/)

Comment: Спасибо большое за исчерпывающий ответ!
APNS-Sharp деприкукунл :) попробуем заюзать 
https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/
тем более он кроссарентированный.

Answer (score 1):

[Отсылка пуша через APN сервис](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html) не бином Ньютона, а кусочек кода который умещается на 1-м экране, что на С/С++, что на Objective-C, что на C#, что на Java.

По сути это отсылка на известный сервер через известный порт, SSL/TLS туннелем JSON строки с неким бинарным оверхедом. Это реализуется на любом нормальном языке просто и быстро, вне зависимости от языка. Так что ваш вопрос считаю некорректным. Примеров в сети можно надыбать простым гуглением.

В конечном итоге все будет зависеть от того в какой среде вы будете делать пуш. Если окружение dot Net, то лучше наверное C#, а если Java, то тут ясен пень без Java никуда.

Comment: Спасибо, это-то все понятно, хотелось бы отзывы, а то велосипед изобрести не долго же.